# Run tests in parallel with surefire and testng

Tags: maven, testing, testng, parallel-testing

I am experimenting how to run tests in parallel with maven surefire and testng. However, the configuration seems not very straightforward and I can't make it work. Below are my dummy tests.

```
@Log4j
public class DummyTest {
    @Test
    public void test_1() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("test 1 started");
        Thread.sleep( 3000 );
        assertTrue(true);
        log.info("test 1 ended");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("test 2 started");
        Thread.sleep( 5000 );
        assertTrue(true);
        log.info("test 2 ended");
    }
}

//------------------------------------
public class Dummy2Test {
    @Test
    public void test_1() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("test 1 started");
        Thread.sleep( 3000 );
        assertTrue(true);
        log.info("test 1 ended");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_2() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("test 2 started");
        Thread.sleep( 5000 );
        assertTrue(true);
        log.info("test 2 ended");
    }
}
```

And this is my surefire configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>all</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The tests are essentially running sequentially. Here are logs as evidence:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
2014-10-14 18:51:18 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test.test_1():12 - test 1 started
2014-10-14 18:51:21 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test.test_1():15 - test 1 ended
2014-10-14 18:51:21 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test.test_2():20 - test 2 started
2014-10-14 18:51:26 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test.test_2():23 - test 2 ended
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.316 sec - in com.tns.ct.tests.Dummy2Test
Running com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest
Configuring TestNG with: TestNG652Configurator
2014-10-14 18:51:27 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest.test_1():12 - test 1 started
2014-10-14 18:51:30 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest.test_1():15 - test 1 ended
2014-10-14 18:51:30 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest.test_2():20 - test 2 started
2014-10-14 18:51:35 INFO  com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest.test_2():23 - test 2 ended
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.318 sec - in com.tns.ct.tests.DummyTest

Results :

Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My intention is to run all tests (down to method level) in parallel. So, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think all is an option for TestNG.  Try with `<parallel>methods<\paralell>` if you want all to testcases to be executed in parallel.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, it is not working very well. In any case, I have solved my problem by having a testng.xml where I specify parallel strategy.

Comment: So without a testng.xml , we cannot run the tests in parallel?

I did try out the sample code and it worked fine for me without including a testng.xml file.
I was able to run the test methods all in parallel.  
I tried with surefire 2.21.0 version and testng 6.8.21